# Are there algorithms that perform hole detection in PCL?

Tags: detection, image-recognition, point-cloud-library, feature-detection, point-clouds

I want to detect a hole (elliptical in shape). Would you recommend any specific algorithms in Point Cloud Library that I could look into?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Lexi this is actually a very specific question about the PCL library, not a general recommendation question. If such a function exists in the library, then there is a very straight forward, factual answer; otherwise the answer is no.

Comment: @NicuStiurca I appreciate the comment. I see where you are coming from. But isn't an algorithm suggestion considered an off-site resource? I believe I flagged it because it wasn't asking how to implement a specific algorithm, but rather looking for a recommendation of one and this seemed opinion-based as a result. I get that it's a specific question about the library, but I think maybe I don't understand why this wouldn't be off topic?

Comment: @Lexi The description of the "too broad" close reason is `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format...` As I said, since the question is scoped to the PCL library, there are not going to be very many (if any!) answers, and each possible answer would be fairly short.